# What options do I have for storing customers basket contents on my website outside of their session?

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

As the title says: What options do I have for storing customers basket contents on my website outside of their session and not logged in to an account?

I do not want to have to request permission for cookies use (EU law). From what I understand, using a cookie to store the basket contents longer than session long, would mean a 'persistent cookie' which requires permission from the visitor before use, clarification would be useful here.  If that is the case, then I don't want to go down the cookie route of asking permission.

I'm wondering if there is some way of doing it via our database, if that is possible how would it record to that unique visitor, I can only think of that it might record an IP address perhaps if that is allowed without gaining prior permission.

I have noticed other websites doing exactly this without asking for permission to use cookies, so I can only assume there is indeed another way!

If I have answered my own question, please clarify the above points to avoid any confusion.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I've been notified of cookie use but never asked for permission.

Comment: Typically, you'd use PHP's native session support, with a database handler for the backend. This still requires a cookie to hold the session id.

Comment: I don't think that is possible to remember a customer without writing (cookies) or reading (IP address, Mac address) a unique identifier.

Comment: You will need to use cookies to store a **unique** ID of user's shopping cart and keep the cart details in your database.

Comment: Here is an example straight from the EU website showing exactly that http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm

I have also seen many sites probably what you are referring to, when a popup in the foot/head of the site requires you to click X to make the message go away. I don't want to have to present either to my customers.

Comment: @Alex Howanksky.  Can you confirm either way if this would/wouldn't be classed as a persistent cookie and therefore wouldn't need to worry about the EU cookie issue in regards to asking/informing the customer about use of cookies on this site?

Comment: You can do it either way -- you get to select the cookie's expiration when you create it. If you don't want to use persistent cookies, then the session will be lost when the user closes their browser, and their cart will be empty the next time they connect.

Comment: @AlexHowansky makes sense, we are already using a session cookie as you describe, but of course once the session is terminated then so is the basket.  I have noticed sites such as 'find me a gift . co . uk' allow me to add a product to the basket close the session and return with the product still in the basket. I'm fairly sure I haven't agreed/been notified of using cookies, would you be so kind to clarify how they might be doing that please?

Comment: _"clarify how they might be doing that "_ To do that reliably requires a persistent cookie.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link any kind of information that is in your DB, basket case for example, to every single customer, you have to identify him.

You can identify him writing a unique id on the server for example, MAC address or IP address(?) or writing a cookie on his client, and again referring to it in your server.

I can't see any other way.

And the meaning of the cookie law is just that to do it, you need the user approval, for this reason I'm quite sure that you can't do this without breaking EU laws.

Comment: Thank you kiks73, I know we can use session cookies without having to ask/notify the user, are you saying in your example that we would need a persistent cookie?

Comment: If you are sure that you can save for ex. your PHP session ID to the client in a persistent cookie without asking for permission, than you can do it

Comment: @AlexHowansky I know that,  the (?) is just for that reason, IP is mentioned in the question

Comment: @kiks73 Thank you. So it would seem there is no way of doing this without the use of a persistent cookie, which I would require permission prior.  I just don't understand sites like find me a gift co uk, do so without first asking permission. They seem to be taking a risk working like this.  Is this your finding also?

Comment: @user1171523 Yes, I think so.